# How to append more data in a .txt file?

Tags: java

I want my program to check if there is data in the text file and add more data below it.

I can write to the file but I don't know how to check if there is already data in the file and how to add more information below it. It currently just overrides the existing information.

```
try (
FileWriter file = new FileWriter("name.txt");
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(file);
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
) {
out.println("Name:" + firstname + " " + middlename + " " + lastname);
out.println("DOB:" + birthday);
out.println("Phone:" + phone);
out.println("Address:" + address);
} catch(IOException e) {
System.out.println("Error!");
}
```

It should add more information below the existing information, not replace it.

For example:
Name: anon anon anon
DOB:010200
Phone:12345678
Address: anon

Then when I run the code again I want it the write the new information below it.

Comment: Google "java append to file if exists" that should get you started

Answer (score 1):

```
FileWriter file = new FileWriter("name.txt", true);
```

The FileWriter constructor takes a parameter `append`. If it is set to true, your data will be appended to the file (i.e. not overwrite it). If it is false, the file is overwritten. [Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter-java.io.File-boolean-) will tell you more.